# Alternative to X-sendfile in Apache for sending file given a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, proxy, amazon-s3

I'm writing a Rails application that serves files stored on a remote server to the end user.

In my case the files are stored on S3 but the user requests the file via the Rails-application (hiding the actual URL). If the file was on my servers local file-system, I could use the Apache header X-Sendfile to free up the Ruby process for other requests while Apache took over the task of sending the file to the client. But in my case - where the file is not on the local file-system, but on S3 - it seems that I'm forced to download it temporarily inside Rails before sending it to the client.

Isn't there a way for Apache to serve a "remote" file to the client that is not actually on the server it self. I don't mind if Apache has to download the file for this to work, as long as I don't have to tie up the Ruby process while it's going on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to do some Ruby stuff before sending the file? You can't just rewrite the URL, you need to hide the S3 URL? Just to clarify

Comment: Not really, but I have two requirements: 1) I would would like to record the download in a log (which is not possible if the client requests the file from S3 directly). 2) I would like the users browser to ask to save the file instead of showing it inside the browser-window (today I use the "Content-Disposition: attachment" header). I don't know if it's possible to force S3 links to download as attachment instead of showing it inline though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas, I have similar requirements/issues and I think I can answer your problem. First (and I'm not 100% sure you care for this part), hiding the S3 url is quite easy as Amazon allows you to point CNAMES to your bucket and use a custom URL instead of the amazon URL. To do that, you need to point your DNS to the correct amazon URL. When I set mine up it was similar to this: files.domain.com points to files.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com. Then you need to create the bucket with the name of your custom URL (files.domain.com in this example). How to call that URL will be different depending on which gem you use, but a word of warning was that the attachment_fu plugin I was using was incorrectly sending me to files.domain.com/files.domain.com/name_of_file.... I couldn't find the setting to fix it, so a simple .sub method for the S3 portion of the plugin fixed it.

On to your other questions, to execute some rails code (like recording the hit in the db) before downloading you can simply do this:

```
def download
  file = File.find(...
  # code to record 'hit' to database
  redirect_to 3Object.url_for(file.filename, 
                              bucket,
                              :expires_in => 3.hours)
end
```

That code will still cause the file to be served by S3, but and still give you the ability to run some ruby. (Of course the above code won't work as is, you will need to point it to the correct file and bucket and my amazon keys are saved in a config file. The above is also using the syntax for the AWS::S3 gem - http://amazon.rubyforge.org/).

Second, the Content-Disposition: attachment issue is a bit more tricky. Hopefully, your situation is a bit more simple than mine and the following solution can work. Assuming the object 'file' (in this example) is the correct S3 object, you can set the disposition to attachment by

```
file.content_disposition = "attachment"
file.save
```

The above code can be executed after the file exists on the S3 server (unlike some other headers and permissions), which is nice and it can also be added when you upload the file (syntax depends on your plugin). I'm still trying to find a way to tell S3 to send it as an attachment and only when requested (not every time), and if you find that, please let me know your solution. I need to be able to sometimes download it and other times save embed images (for example) into HTML. I'm not using the above mentioned redirect but fortunately it seems that if you embed (such as a HTML image tag) a file with the content-disposition/attachment header, and the browser still displays the image normally (but I haven't throughly tested that across enough browsers to send it in the wild).

Hope that helps! Good luck.

Comment: I found out that Amazon S3 does allow you to set custom headers for each file. This means that you can easily set a Content-Disposition header when storing the file on S3. You can see how I've achieved it here: https://gist.github.com/798393

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I also figured out that I can't set custom headers for each file but also found that you can set the Content-Disposition header when storing but had yet to implement it. I will take a look at your code.